# How to deal with foreign keys when moving a postgres database between machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys

I'm trying to move a postgres database between machines as I move from one development platform to another.  I have `yaml_db` gem installed on both machines.

On my old platform I do:

```
rake db:scheme:dump
rake db:data:dump
```

When I go to `reload` the database on my new machine I've discovered that my 2 dozen `foreign_keys` are preventing me for loading my data.  What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pg_dump command to dump your database using:

eg:

```
pg_dump -U <user-name> -h <host> <database> > <file-name>.sql

pg_dump -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 database1 > database1.sql
```

Then copy file to other machine and run following command to restore database

```
psql <database-name> < path/to/sql_dump_file

psql database1 < database1.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You're copying a database, Rails really shouldn't have anything to do with the process (and as you're seeing, it just gets in the way).

Instead, put on your DBA hat and copy the database without bothering with Rails. Dump the data using [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) and then restore the data with [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html). The database's backup/restore tools know all about foreign keys, triggers, extensions, and anything else that Railsy tools don't understand.